# Entity Framework: Manually setting entity state reverting values

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I am using EF5 in a disconnected manner.  I have a main table called `Cases` with lookup tables for various things with associations defined.  For example, the column `SOURCE_ID` is associated with a `Sources` table, where that table contains the lookups.

In the entity for `Cases` I have the Source_ID column as well as the association and navigation property called `Source` to navigate to the associated table.

Since I am using things in a disconnected manner, when I want to save the entity, I manually set the state from `Added` to `Modified`.  This works well (following some examples in Julie Lermon's book).

What happens though is that if I change the `SOURCE_ID` column to a different value and the associated table was loaded with the entity, when I change the state to `MODIFIED`, the `SOURCE_ID` reverts back to the original value, presumably because of the association.

I am loading the associated `SOURCES` table because I want to display other stuff from that table, but I simply want to change the `SOURCE_ID` and save it.  It seems not to like that.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This looks like normal behavior because of the primary key relationship.

Comment: so you are saying that you modified the column in the database?  Then when you set the state on your entity to modified and savechanges to reverts the value back in the database?  Or is source_id an int property on your model?  Or is source_id the PK on sources model, and your case has a source?

Comment: It would help to see the code where this all happens. Very likely someone (or I) will see a line that needs a slight change.

Answer (score 0):

Needs more code, but I'll take a shot.

Instead of just updating the SOURCE_ID, try updating your reference to the Sources lookup.

So instead of....

```
Case.Source.ID = 1;
```

Maybe....

```
Case.Source = db.Sources.Where(x => x.SOURCE_ID == 1).FirstOrDefault();
```

(edit: oh, this was asked a month ago?  oops. well, still.)